# storage to avoid commandbuffer recording

Tags: vulkan

I have several one-time `VkCommandBuffer` reset and recorded at each frame, just because of a few changing push constants.

Would it be more efficient (faster and/or a better practice) to move those changing data into a buffer (storage or uniform) so to record the command buffers only once?

I have read somewhere that command buffer recording may be quite CPU intensive, but I don't know if it is either true or still valid.

Comment: "*command buffer recording may be quite expensive*" Expensive for what part of your software? Expensive relative to what?

Comment: @NicolBolas right, I meant CPU intensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be more efficient (faster and/or a better practice) to move those changing data into a buffer (storage or uniform) so to record the command buffers only once?

As it turns out, after a week of testing, no.

Command buffer recording (at least in my case) was so fast that it simply made no sense at all to switch to storage buffers just to skip the recording phase.

Of course this may change from case to case, so everybody should go ahead with their own testing.